# Troubles with emails started with "-"(dash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

We have Ruby On Rails application with some emails subscription. It has mailer class inherited from ActionMailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
...
end
```

Everything ok, except one thing - some users have email addresses with "-" at begin.
It occur errors when I'm trying send email to "-user@mailinator.com":

```
sendmail: invalid option -- u
sendmail: invalid option -- s
sendmail: invalid option -- u
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
```

How could I escape this character(and maybe some similar) for ActionMailer?

Thanks

Comment: you would need to escape this special character because its an option character in all bash/shell commands

Comment: Many unix commands stop parsing parameters after `--` argument. Maybe you could reconfigure sendmail calling code to do that?

Comment: Thanks for advises. I've try add some escaping:
- adding `\` and additional `"` or `'` doesn't help(emails to "\"-user@mailinator.com\"", "\-user@mailinator.com" and "-\'user@mailinator.com\'" were sent, but inbox at "-user@mailinator.com" remained empty)
- adding `/` unexpectedly helps: email to "/-user@mailinator.com" sends and delivers to "-user@mailinator.com".

Also I'll try override sendmail method in application.

Comment: This should rails issue on Github - It should be escaping those characters, although it only appears when config.delivery_method is :sendmail - using :sendmail is still a rails-core.. Or well actually ActionMailer..

Answer (score 1):

The URI.escape method although deprecated does take a second parameter that lets you mark what's unsafe like so

```
URI.escape("-user@mailinator.com", '-')
=> "%2Duser@mailinator.com"
```

CGI escape which replaces URI.escape doesn't seem to have the same functionality but for a single case like this it might work.